# Div height in percentage not working in IE11?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

i am using 4 divs namely divView_1,divView_2,divView_3 and divView_4.
these divs are genereted inside telerik Pane.
I am calling the css every time divs are created.
Divs are created on treeview checkbox selection... 
if one checkbox is being selected then only divView_1 should be visible with height and width 100% of the browser screen.
if two checkbox are being selected then both divView_1 and divView_2 should be visible with height=100% and width=50% of the browser screen.
if three or four checkbox is being selected then all the divs should be visible with the same height and width of 50% of the browser screen.

i am using css for it and css is calling every time the checkbox is selected.
The code is working fine in chrome but is not working correctly in Internet Explorer version 11.
In IE, Divs width are working fine but height is becoming only of 2 px; What is the problem behind it?

```
    for (var y = 1; y <= value; y++)
    {
     var player_Parent=$('[id$=divView_' + y + ']');
     append_Player(noOfPlayers, player_Parent); 
    }
    function append_Player(no_of_Players, player_Parent_iOS)
    { 
      if (no_of_Players == 1)
      { $(player_Parent_iOS).attr('class','single'); }
      else if (no_of_Players == 2) 
     { $(player_Parent_iOS).attr('class', 'double'); } 
    }
```

CSS is as following..

```
     .single 
      {
         height:100%; width:100%; display:block; border-width:thin;
      }
     .double
      {
        height:100%; width:50%; border-width:thin;  border-style:solid;
       }
```

Comment: where is code.. Must display your code what have you tried

Comment: Please show your code then we can help you.

Comment: @ManishJain What a mess. You put the code in the question. Also use some formatting so we cant read the question.